# 3 poles Thyristor ploblem in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I can't understand placing a 3-poles something in the circuit. there is a little circuit and I know it's not the good way to make a circuit but I want you to show me to change the hey C with a npn Thyristor.  I read the manual of circuitikz and can't make it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw 
(0,0)   

to [battery](0,4) 
[short] -- ++ (3,0)
          to [C, l_=hey] (4,4)
            [short] -- ++ (2,0)
        to [L] (8,4)
           [short] -- ++ (2,0)
          to [R] (10,0)
          (10,0) -- (0,0)

         (2,4) to [C](2,0)
           (5,0) to [Do](5,4)

 ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not fully sure want you want to achieve, but maybe something like this can help?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to [battery]  (0,4) 
             [short] -- ++ (3,0)
             to [Ty]       (4,4)
             [short] -- ++ (2,0)
             to [L]        (8,4)
             [short] -- ++ (2,0)
             to [R]        (10,0)

       (10,0) --           (0,0)

       (2,4) to [C]        (2,0)

       (5,0) to [Do]       (5,4)
 ;
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to [battery]  (0,4) 
             [short] -- ++ (3,0)
             node [npn,anchor=C,rotate=90] (npn) {} 

       (npn.E) --       ++ (2,0)
             to [L]        (8,4)
             [short] -- ++ (2,0)
             to [R]        (10,0)

       (10,0) --           (0,0)

       (2,4) to [C]        (2,0)

       (5,0) to [Do]       (5,4)
 ;
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to [battery]  (0,4) 
             [short] -- ++ (3,0)
             node [npn,anchor=E,rotate=-90] (npn) {} 

       (npn.C) --       ++ (2,0)
             to [L]        (8,4)
             [short] -- ++ (2,0)
             to [R]        (10,0)

       (10,0) --           (0,0)

       (2,4) to [C]        (2,0)

       (5,0) to [Do]       (5,4)
 ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For the thyristor, it has an anode, a cathode and a gate. Give the thyristor a name (thyris in this case), and you can use the anchors as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [battery](0,4) 
               [short] -- ++ (3,0)
            to [C, l_=hey] (4,4)
               [short] -- ++ (2,0)
            to [L] (8,4)
               [short] -- ++ (2,0)
            to [R] (10,0)
     (10,0) -- (0,0)
      (2,4) to [C](2,0)
      (5,0) to [Ty, n=thyris](5,4)
    (3,2.7) to (thyris.gate) node[below] {G}    % wire to gate
               (thyris.anode) node[right] {A}   % the anode
               (thyris.cathode) node[right] {C} % the cathode
    (3,2.7) to [battery] (3,0)
            ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```